# How do I send a raw CI-V command via rigctl?

Tags: icom, ci-v

With my ICom 9700 the [CI-V reference manual](https://www.icomjapan.com/uploads/support/manual/IC-9700_ENG_CI-V_3a.pdf) says that I should be able to send the command 0x07, subcommand 0xD0, to select the Main band, and 0xD1 to select the Sub band. subcommend 0xB0 to exchange Main and Sub bands.

From the [rigctl manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libhamlib-utils/rigctl.1.en.html) I expect the `send_cmd` (`w`) command to let me send `w \0x07\0xB0` to exchange the Main and Sub bands.

When I send this, rigctl doesn't give an error. But it also does nothing.

I also tried sending the full CI-V packet, `w \0xFE\0xEF\0xA2\0xE0\0x07\0xB0\0xFD`, but also that is silently accepted with no action taken.

I look at the radio, and nothing changes, and I also use the `f` command, and see that still the same band is active. (same frequency is returned)

So: how do I send this raw command to exchange Sub and Main band.

Alternatively: Is there a way to use existing rigctl commands to do this? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried sending the full CI-V packet, `w \0xFE\0xEF\0xA2\0xE0\0x07\0xB0\0xFD`

The sync word is `FE FE`, not `FE EF`; that might be your whole problem. Otherwise it looks like this one is right.

> Alternatively: Is there a way to use existing rigctl commands to do this? I couldn't find one.

`v MAIN`, `v SUB`, and `G XCHG` should work (I don't have a 9700 here to test).

Comment: The `v` / `V` command doesn't seem to work on the 9700, but other than that you were spot on. Thank you!

Comment: @thomas you might want to make sure that your version of hamlib is new enough :)

Answer (score 1):

I used this option:
To your rig:

rigctl -m 2 w '\0xFE\0xFE\0xA2\0xE0\0x07\0xB0\0xFD'

to my IC-718 to LSB mode:

rigctl -m 2 w '\0xFE\0xFE\0x5E\0xE0\0x06\0x00\0xFD'